# How to update a package.json dependency?

Tags: package.json

This is currently what I'm dealing with:
[image: screenshot]

I tried deleting the `node_modules` and then running `npm install` in the terminal because I read that doing so would update all packages. I uploaded the changes to GitHub but the message is still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

Comment: When I run npm i -g npm-check-updates I get the following error in the terminal: Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: open cmd as administrator and try it again

Comment: Cmd or terminal

Comment: Sorry guys but how do I open the cmd in the terminal?

Comment: what do u mean?  in windows just on serach type cmd and open as administrator by right cliking it

Comment: I'm using a mac and I'm not sure what you guys mean with open cmd as administrator, I'm googling too.

Comment: To switch to root so that all subsequent commands are executed with high privileges instead of using sudo before each command use following command and then provide the password when prompted.

sudo -i

Comment: Well I was able to update the packages, the changes to GitHub but I still get the same message. I also deleted the node_modules before uploading the changes because I get a few errors for some reason but I don't think that should matter?